# Posix Timer on SCHED_RR Thread is using 100% CPU

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>

int main() {
    std::thread rr_thread([](){
      struct sched_param params = {5};
      pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_RR, &params);

      struct itimerspec ts;
      struct epoll_event ev;
      int tfd ,epfd;

      ts.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        ts.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
        ts.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        ts.it_value.tv_nsec = 20000; // 50 kHz timer

      tfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);
      timerfd_settime(tfd, 0, &ts, NULL);
      epfd = epoll_create(1);

      ev.events = EPOLLIN;
      epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, tfd, &ev);

      while (true) {
        epoll_wait(epfd, &ev, 1, -1); // wait forever for the timer
        read(tfd, &missed, sizeof(missed));

        // Here i have a blocking function (dummy in this example) which
        // takes on average 15ns to execute, less than the timer period anyways
        func15ns();
      }

    });

    rr_thread.join();
}
```

I have a posix thread using the SCHED_RR policy and on this thread there is a POSIX Timer running with a timeout of 20000ns = 50KHz = 50000 ticks/sec.

After the timer fires i am executing a function that takes roughly 15ns so less than the timer period, but this doesn't really matter.

When i execute this i am getting 100% CPU Usage, the whole system is getting slow but i don't understand why this is happening and some things are confusing.

1. Why 100% CPU Usage since the thread is supposed to be sleeping while waiting for the timer to fire, so other tasks can be scheduled in theory right? even if this is a high priority thread.
2. I checked using pidstat the number of context switches and it seems that it's very small, close to 0, both voluntary and involuntary ones. Is this normal? While waiting for the timer to fire the scheduler should schedule other tasks right? I should see at least 20000 * 2 context switches / sec

Comment: 50 kHz is pretty hardcore for a timer. If you can get it, you're spending a LOT of time servicing it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yeah sorry, my bad, it's late here, i'll change that

Comment: I'm not sure 50kHz is even doable on most common hardware.  Most likely the timer is going off "as fast as possible" (hence the 100% CPU usage) but not 50,000 times per second.

Answer (score 2):

As presented, your program does not behave as you describe.  This is because you program the timer as a one-shot, not a repeating timer.  For a timer that fires every 20000 ns, you want to set a 20000-ns interval:

```
    ts.it_interval.tv_nsec = 20000;
```

Having modified that, I get a program that works produces heavy load on one core.

> 1. Why 100% CPU Usage since the thread is supposed to be sleeping while waiting for the timer to fire, so other tasks can be scheduled
>      in theory right? even if this is a high priority thread.

Sure, your thread blocks in `epoll_wait()` to await timer ticks, if in fact it manages to loop back there before the timer ticks again.  On my machine, your program consumes only about 30% of one core, which seems to confirm that such blocking will indeed happen.  That you see 100% CPU use suggests that my computer runs the program more efficiently than yours does, for whatever reason.

But you have to appreciate that the load is *very* heavy.  You are asking to perform all the processing of the timer itself, the epoll call, the read, and `func15ns()` once every 20000 ns.  Yes, whatever time may be left, if any, is available to be scheduled for another task, but the task swap takes a bit more time again.  20000 ns is not very much time.  Consider that just [fetching a word from main memory costs about 100 ns](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html) (though reading one from cache is of course faster).

In particular, do not neglect the work other than `func15ns()`.  If the latter indeed takes only 15 ns to run then it's the least of your worries.  You're performing two system calls, and these are expensive.  Just how expensive depends on a lot of factors, but consider that removing the `epoll_wait()` call reduces the load for me from 30% to 25% of a core (and note that the whole epoll setup is superfluous here because simply allowing the `read()` to block serves the purpose).

> 2. I checked using pidstat the number of context switches and it seems that it's very small, close to 0, both voluntary and involuntary
>      ones. Is this normal? While waiting for the timer to fire the
>      scheduler should schedule other tasks right? I should see at least
>      20000 * 2 context switches / sec

You're occupying a full CPU with a high priority task, so why do you expect switching?

On the other hand, I'm also observing a low number of context switches for the process running your (modified) program, even though it's occupying only 25% of a core. I'm not prepared at the moment to reason about why that is.